# Не работает setNavigationItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-drawer

При нажатии на Item не выходит Toast. Подскажите пожалуйста если видите ошибку.

код Main_activity:

```
package kg.tutorialapp.homework_38

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout)

    val navView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)

    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close)
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Clicked Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.nav_message -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Clicked Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.nav_settings -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Clicked Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.nav_help -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Clicked Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        true
    }

}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

Comment: Мало информации, попробуйте расширить вопрос разметкой и xml навигации. Так же посмотрите на возможные решения здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486796/setnavigationitemselectedlistener-not-working

Comment: Спасибо, нашла ошибку. Оказывается NavigationView должен быть в Drawer Layout(разметка) последним ребенком т.е. добавила элемент перед NavigationView и все заработало.